# is there a way to handle a messy variable in R?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I have the following dataset. I am trying to pivot_wider that each tmc_code be a column and the values are from speed. and then lag and lead some values. However, if you look at tmc_code, the values are weird and I cannot change them. I want to give them names that I can deal with. for example, the value "119+04117" better be "tmc119_04117". I guess R does not like the "+" in a value or a variable. Please let me know if I need to restate the question. I know it is a messy question but my dataset is really confusing. Here is a sample of my dataset.

```
data<- structure(list(tmc_code = c("119P04108", "119P04109", "119+04117",
                                   "119+04106", "119+04110", "119+04113", 
                                  "119+04111", "119P04107", "119+04110", 
                                  "119P04117", "119+04114", "119+04107",
                                   "119+04112" ), 
             measurement_tstamp = c("2020-06-05 20:10:00", "2020-08-26 10:30:00", 
                                    "2020-11-15 18:20:00", "2020-10-16 13:20:00",  
                                    "2020-09-17 00:20:00", "2020-02-09 15:10:00",  
                                    "2020-03-19 09:15:00", "2020-11-05 03:25:00", 
                                    "2020-07-23 22:35:00", "2020-11-25 22:05:00", 
                                    "2020-03-28 07:40:00", "2020-02-14 22:20:00", 
                                    "2020-05-01 16:25:00"), 
speed = c(69, 64, 74.39, 63.37, 61.8, 71.39, 61, 68.4, 74.18, 62.8, 64, 70.98, 
          66.53)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

my code for pivot_wider is

```
data<- data%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = tmc_code, values_from = speed)
```

Comment: Yes, I guess the values with p do not make a problem in R.  have no problem with any value that I can read and recognize. @akrun

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Op's comment:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(tmc_code = str_replace_all(tmc_code, "\\+", "_")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = tmc_code, 
    values_from = speed
  )
```

Output:

```
  measurement_tstamp  `119P04108` `119P04109` `119_04117` `119_04106` `119_04110` `119_04113` `119_04111` `119P04107` `119P04117` `119_04114` `119_04107` `119_04112`
   <chr>                     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2020-06-05 20:10:00          69          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 2 2020-08-26 10:30:00          NA          64        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 3 2020-11-15 18:20:00          NA          NA        74.4        NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 4 2020-10-16 13:20:00          NA          NA        NA          63.4        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 5 2020-09-17 00:20:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          61.8        NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 6 2020-02-09 15:10:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          71.4          NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 7 2020-03-19 09:15:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            61        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
 8 2020-11-05 03:25:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        68.4        NA            NA        NA          NA  
 9 2020-07-23 22:35:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          74.2        NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          NA  
10 2020-11-25 22:05:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          62.8          NA        NA          NA  
11 2020-03-28 07:40:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            64        NA          NA  
12 2020-02-14 22:20:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        71.0        NA  
13 2020-05-01 16:25:00          NA          NA        NA          NA          NA          NA            NA        NA          NA            NA        NA          66.5
```

Comment: I will not keep the true speed values. I will be getting 1 for each value and that is not what I really want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
reshape(
  data,
  idvar = "measurement_tstamp",
  timevar = "tmc_code",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

or

```
reshape(
  transform(
    data,
    tmc_code = gsub("(\\w{3}).(.*)", "tmc\\1_\\2", tmc_code)
  ),
  idvar = "measurement_tstamp",
  timevar = "tmc_code",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

or

```
reshape(
  transform(
    data,
    tmc_code = paste0("tmc",gsub("\\+","_", tmc_code))
  ),
  idvar = "measurement_tstamp",
  timevar = "tmc_code",
  direction = "wide"
)
```

or

```
data %>%
  mutate(tmc_code = paste0("tmc", gsub("\\+", "_", tmc_code))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = tmc_code, values_from = speed)
```

Comment: That code seems to be working. However, there are some values in the tmc_code that will have the same name if we apply the same process on the (+ and P). I have 25 tmc_code values. Therefore, I am receiving 13 columns instead of 25.

Comment: @mustafa What about the newly updated answer? check it out.

Comment: That worked great. I will accept that answer but first please let me work with it and let you know if I have any new comments. Thank You!

Comment: I am receiving the following error (There were 25 warnings (use warnings() to see them)) what that means?

Comment: The last one gives me good looking output. however, I am getting the same original error (Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates )

Comment: @mustafa I have no idea why you have those warnings....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that column names start with a digit and they also contain the plus operator.

Using stringr and tidyverse libraries.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data$tmc_code <-  str_replace(data$tmc_code, pattern = '\\+', replacement = '_') %>% 
    str_replace(pattern = '^.', replacement = '\\x') 

data_spread <- as_tibble(data) %>%
    spread(tmc_code, speed)
```